# CentOS - upstart script is created, but its never running at all

Tags: bash, centos, upstart, runlevel

I have this following setup but its not working in my CentOS 6x (3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 18 14:48:24 CET 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Step 1: vi /etc/init/a.conf

```
description "a.js"
author "YumYumYum"

# Stanzas
#
# Stanzas control when and how a process is started and stopped
# See a list of stanzas here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#respawn

# When to start the service
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

script
  echo $$ > /var/run/a.pid;
  exec node /var/tmp/signal/a.js
end script

post-stop script
  rm -f /var/run/a.pid
end script
```

Step 2:

```
$ service a start
a: unrecognized service
```

How do i run it please?

Comment: `initctl start a`

Comment: I just applied and i checked the process, but now its running my a.js twice. i have two time same server script running.

Answer (score -1):

That looks like an upstart service. You can run it using:

```
initctl start a
```